# WordPress - page content not updating in front-end

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I have a problem with a WordPress site.

When I am trying to update page content or edit css file, changes not appearing in front-end. It looks like cache problem, but I empty my cache every time and nothing helps. I should wait some hours or try another browser to see changes that I've made.

I am not using any cahce plugins and don't know why content changes take so long to go live.

Please help me.

Comment: Without more information it's going to be hard to help you. Your question is too broad for proper informed answers in it's present state,

Comment: Are you using a pre-built theme? Do you have a link to the site/theme? If you navigate to the CSS file directly on the site, do you see the changes in there? If you create a new page within Wordpress and change content on there, does that work? Really need a bit more info here.

Answer (score 0):

This is standart browser cache for CSS and JS files. You can reload page with CTRL+SHIFT+R buttons. If you want to display your new CSS for all users, you need to change the version of CSS-file in your theme. Read More: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this kind of issues these days too, what I do is, in the

```
      wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

in `$ver` i place php function `time()` it changes after every second, I think this technique is best for development purpose.

so the final enque will be

```
     wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', filesourse/file.js, array(''), time(), true );
```

for the `style` you can also use `time()` at the `$ver` position

```
   wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle', filesourse/file.css, array(''), time(), 'all' );
```

Hope this will work for you too,

Answer (score 0):

If you have cache folder in your rootfolder rename it and try,because your all site configuration store that cache folder in root folder.